# R Plot values that select column based on a provided index value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to figure out how to plot some values in a peculiar way. Say I have the example data below:

```
set.seed(100)
test.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:36,nrow=6))
test.df$V7 <- sample(1:6,6)
test.df$V8 <- seq(1:6)
colnames(test.df) <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","index","id")
test.df

    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 index id
1    1    7   13   19   25   31     2  1
2    2    8   14   20   26   32     6  2
3    3    9   15   21   27   33     3  3
4    4   10   16   22   28   34     1  4
5    5   11   17   23   29   35     4  5
6    6   12   18   24   30   36     5  6
```

I want to plot values from the first 6 columns by using the "index" column as a means of selecting which column (1-6) to choose from. This would be the y axis. The x axis would be "id". Essentially, the first y value would be 7 because index selects column 2 for the first value. The second y value would 32 because the index value indicates column 6.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything else. I'm fairly new to plotting in R (ggplot2 or otherwise), so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of ggplot2.

First, you can create a column `y':

```
test.df[, "y"] <- 0
for (i in (1:nrow(test.df))) {
test.df[i, "y"] <- test.df[i, paste0("col", test.df[i, "index"])]
    }
```

Then you can do the plotting, with `plot`:

```
plot(y ~ id, data = test.df, type = "l")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works for my problem.